# What is Web SQL Database int max value?

Tags: cordova, web-sql

In Web SQL Database, what is a int max value?
(exactly in Safari on iOS 7)

I didn't find anything in docs: http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently all implementations of web-sql use SQLite ([says Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database) and the spec says "User agents must implement the SQL dialect supported by Sqlite 3.6.19").

SQLite's [maxint value](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) is `2^63-1 = 9223372036854775807`